# Using a4j , how would you rerender a dojo component?

Tags: jsf, dojo, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I am using JSF 1.2 and Richfaces 3.3.3 ,  I've tried

```
<a4j:region>
 <t:selectOneMenu id="comp1" value="#{bB.selectedTeam}" style="width: 200px">
    <t:selectItems value="#{bB.teams}" var="team" itemLabel="#{team.desc}" itemValue="#{team.code}"/>
        <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="comp2"/>
  </t:selectOneMenu>
```

but didn't work.
comp1 is a Dojo combobox component and it doesn't do anything when onchange event happens.

Comment: Do you have a <h:form> around that? What scope does your bB bean have? If it's request scoped, that might be the problem.

Comment: yeah, all those things are fine, I actually tested it and worked well,  but stopped to work when through css I  converted comp1 to a Dojo component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out the   html object rendered by `<t:selectItems>` was transformed to a dijit component when page loads,  that conversion to dojo in javascript side does that the user won't interact with the  object we indicated to do ajax call in the event onchange through

```
<a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="comp2"/>
```

so the solution was to use   in order to attach the event to the dojo component  in javascript browser side.

Answer (score 0):

JSF doesn't keep track of plain HTML. If you want to be able to rerender something it has to be wrapped in a component, like `<a4j:outputPanel>` and then you have to rerender that component.

Comment: I thought he might be using http://www.dojofaces.org/ in that case it should work.

Comment: @noone well I don't know but going by the tag it is a JavaScript library